# Why Does DC Use Fictional City Names?

Tags: comics, dc, marvel

It seems to be one of the major differences between DC and Marvel. Where the Marvel comics are set in New York, LA ... etc., DC uses fictional cities like Metropolis, Gotham and Star City.

Was this a conscious decision from the start?

Comment: That way heroes from each universe don't accidentally end up in each other comic panels.

Comment: CatWoman was set in New York for a while, and one of the JL comics in Detroit. DC does use real world cities, just not as much as Marvel and Marvel mostly just use New York.

Answer (score 13):

> Writer Bill Finger, on the naming of the city and the reason for changing Batman's locale from New York City to a fictional city said, "Originally I was going to call Gotham City 'Civic City'. Then I tried 'Capital City', then 'Coast City'. Then I flipped through the New York City phone book and spotted the name 'Gotham Jewelers' and said, 'That's it,' Gotham City.
>   **We didn't call it New York because we wanted anybody in any city to identify with it**.

Source:  Steranko, Jim (1970). The Steranko History of Comics. Reading, Pa.: Supergraphics. p. 44. (via [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotham_City#cite_ref-0))

I wasn't able to find any stated reasons for not naming Metropolis - It couldn't have been in imitation of Gotham since Metropolis dates to September 1939 Action Comics issue #16 whereas Gotham to 1940 Batman #4.

Comment: I've been to [Metropolis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis,_Illinois). There's a cool Superman Museum there lol.

Comment: As that wiki page points out though, "Gotham" was already a nickname for New York City even before its use in comics.

Comment: @DVK - Well that covers Batman I guess. What about the rest? Has it, because of precedent with Supes and Bats, become standard DC MO?

Comment: @SystemDown: Frequently.  Flash was based in Central City, for example, which has been shown as being in several different states at different times.  Also consider Smallville.

Comment: I believe Metropolis is distinct from Gotham as Joe Shuster was Canadian and it was modelled on Toronto (rather than NY for Gotham). This is why the paper is the Daily Planet as he worked for the Toronto Star.

Answer (score 5):

OK well this is just a theory that went around Comic Vine a while ago but it was never truly confirmed.

Basically once you put a name on a city like Gotham and you call it Chicago or New York you are setting limits on it. By calling Gotham Chicago you might not be able to make it seem like such a bad city or the people of Chicago might get mad or something like that. In addition it could limit the geography of the city. For example if DC needs Gotham to be near one city and another time it needs to be close to a different city it would be hard to choose which City Metropolis or Star City would have to be to suit an needs. Like if you said Metropolis is Kansas City and you want to write a superman story that has mountains in it/or in a Forrest or something like that it would be harder to do that. Also in the Dc Arrow verse the city Hong Kong exist and in a version a superman I remember Moscow existed.

Then I did some more thinking and I noticed that in the DC universe most cities have one "protecting" hero like Batman in Gotham, Arrow in Star City, Superman in Metropolis, Flash in Central City, Green Lantern in Coast City etc. Any real cities do not have an individual superhero. The only times that we see these real cities are on occasion where some bad guy is attacking it or the hero are on some sort of "special mission." But will not be mentioned in regular.

Marvel on the other hand does not have a single hero for each city(as of my current knowledge). Thor has Asgard but that is just where he is from he protects all of earth and even the universe in some comics. Iron man, Captain America don't have specific city that they protect either. And because of that there was no need to go though the effort and making up a city that might be used two to three times. So to answer your question it probably was a conscious decision from the start to use fictional names.

Comment: Most of Marvel comics are set in New York.. Spider Man, Fantastic Four, The Avengers, X-men. They may operate globally in some cases, but they are all homed in New York city or New York state. And if you think about it that means that New York is hit with a ton crime in the Marvel Universe